# Как скачать Python packages без интернета?

Tags: python, сервер

Я уже загуглила все способы, попробовала, но выдаются ошибки.

Если я делаю вот так:

```
pip download -r requirements.txt
```

То выходит ошибка:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CB3A5BB220>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pysftp/
```

Мой requirements.txt

```
pysftp
pathlib
datetime
paramiko
pandas
xlrd
pyodbc
excel
numpy
sqlalchemy
```

Мои wheels:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы представляете себе скачивание чего либо без интернета? xD

Comment: Если у Вас локально есть wheels, то их по одному можно установить командой: `pip install package.whl`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 я так попробовала сделать, но там выходит ошибка типа данный wheel не поддерживается.

Comment: @MRO Тогда попробуйте для начала выяснить, почему он не поддерживается. Можете привести эту ошибку в вопрос?

Comment: Какая у вас версия Python? Какая платформа (Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc.) и какая "битность" (32-bit, 64-bit)?

Comment: @nomnoms12 ERROR: bcrypt-3.2.0-cp36-abi3-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: @MaxU и на моем компе и на сервере windows 64-бит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перед установкой "wheel" файла, `pip` предварительно сравнивает следующие компоненты с соответствующими компонентами вашей системы и установленной у вас версии Python:

1. платформу (Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc.)
2. "битность" (32-bit, 64-bit) "wheel" файла
3. версию Python

---

По имени "wheel" файла, чаще всего, можно распознать все описанные выше компоненты.

Пример: `bcrypt-3.2.0-cp36-abi3-win32.whl`:

- Имя модуля: `bcrypt`
- Версия модуля: `3.2.0`
- собран для Python версии 3.6 (CPython реализация)
- собран для платформы Windows, для `32-bit`ной версии Python

---

Если вы, например, установили Python 3.8 (64-bit) на Windows, то и "wheel" файлы нужно скачивать соответствующие.

Например: `bcrypt-3.2.0-cp38-abi3-win64.whl`

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Вы не знаете, почему wheels собираются 32, если 64 бит стоит?

Comment: у меня оказывается 64 бит комп, но python 32 :( не знаю как так получилось.